# Azure's Security Center highlights recommendations to be carried out. For instance "Enable auditing and logging"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have been searching for a way to do this programmatically, rather than manually going through thousands of items via the portal. I'd like to be able to run some PowerShell to enable all logging and push this to a centralised analytical workspace.

I can't seem to find any way to do this via Powershell or any other programmatical approach.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to accomplish what you are looking for using the Security Center REST APIs. For exmaple, see the assessment return here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/securitycenter/assessments/get

You can call this API easily via PowerShell and the Az module with the `Invoke-AzRestMethod` command, which will take care of authentication and return a PowerShell object/array of objects you can work with.

Another option is to export Security Center recommendations and alerts to Log Analytics--https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/continuous-export?tabs=azure-portal#information-about-exporting-to-a-log-analytics-workspace

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't believe the SC API would allow me to make changes to any service items. I probably didn't phrase my question very well, apologies. I want to action the items in the list, IE enable all logging options and point to a specific Analytic WorkSpace.